# model field named url and django rest framework url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I started to use the great django-rest-framework days ago.
I'm not able to solve this simple issue.

My model contains a models.URLField named url.

My serializers.py file:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')    

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('url', 'owner', 'title', 'abstract', 'category', 'position', 'param1')
```

Checking the API result the field 'url' is populated with model.URLField.

```
"results": [
        {
            "url": "http://www.web.com", 
            "owner": "me", 
            "title": "title of the stuff"
        }
```

Instead I would like to have

```
"results": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/en/apiv1/maps/4/", 
            "url_in_model": "http://www.web.com", 
            "owner": "me", 
            "title": "Forest fire"
        }
```

How can I solve?
Thanks

Comment: Ummm....re-name your model field?

Comment: I know, but it's not so feasible. I would like to keep this as last last option. Ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, you may not have much of a choice. If the benefit of using django-rest outweighs the inconvenience of having to change your model field name slightly, then I would change the name. You can always display the label for the field as "Url" instead of whatever you might change it to.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will do as you suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It may be considered poor form (I am by no means a pro programmer or rest_framework expert), but I believe you can add extra context to the serialized output:

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-fields-explicitly

---

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.CharField(source='get_absolute_url', read_only=True)
    groups = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

Extra fields can correspond to any property or callable on the model.

---

So in the above the field 'get_absolute_url' must be in the 'Account' model.
In your case (I think) you could do this:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    url_in_model = serializer.Field(source='url')    

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('url', 'url_in_model', 'owner', 'title', 'abstract', 'category', 'position', 'param1')
```

Of course you would pick the field type that suits.

I haven't had the chance to test this, so there is the chance that using  'url' as your source causes an issue and you may want to name your model field something else - apologies if that is the case and I have wasted your time.

Hope I have helped.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer didn't work for me in DRF 3. I got my model's `url` data for both `url` and `url_in_model`. To get the correct `url` value from DRF, it looked like:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='account-detail')
    url_in_model = serializer.URLField(source='url')  

    class Meta:
        model = Account
```

`account-detail` should be replaced with whatever view corresponds to a single Account.

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to set the default hyperlinked field to another name altogether.

You can do this via the `URL_FIELD_NAME` setting.

Source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#changing-the-url-field-name

e.g: `URL_FIELD_NAME = 'key'` (default is 'url')

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to avoid the conflict is to set `URL_FIELD_NAME` in `settings.py` like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "URL_FIELD_NAME": "api_url", // <---- add this 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## the above answers are not precise.It is simply to control the name of url(default is 'url') by using the key "url_field_name".

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   url_field_name='test-url'
   class Meta:
       model = UserInfo
       extra_kwargs = {
        'test-url': {
            'view_name': '<your view name defined on urls.py>',
            'lookup_field': '<lookup_field>',
            'lookup_url_kwarg': '<lookup_url_kwarg>'
          }
       }
       fields = ['test-url']  #remember include your defined url name
```

## the source code of ModelSerializer in serializer.py

```
def get_fields(self):
    """
    Return the dict of field names -> field instances that should be
    used for `self.fields` when instantiating the serializer.
    """
    if self.url_field_name is None:
        self.url_field_name = api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME

    assert hasattr(self, 'Meta'), (
        'Class {serializer_class} missing "Meta" attribute'.format(
            serializer_class=self.__class__.__name__
        )
    )
    assert hasattr(self.Meta, 'model'), (
        'Class {serializer_class} missing "Meta.model" attribute'.format(
            serializer_class=self.__class__.__name__
        )
    )
    if model_meta.is_abstract_model(self.Meta.model):
        raise ValueError(
            'Cannot use ModelSerializer with Abstract Models.'
        )

    declared_fields = copy.deepcopy(self._declared_fields)
    model = getattr(self.Meta, 'model')
    depth = getattr(self.Meta, 'depth', 0)
```

Answer (score -2):

Nginx needs to be configured correctly, put your ip in the PROXY_PASS

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Change http://127.0.0.1:8003 by http://this-is-my-ip-address.com/[port]